# Insert data of column to another column based on the data of the other column using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have this problem to put data in a column depending of the value the data in its row is `Primary` or `Secondary`

Here's my example:

This is my `source.xlsx` where I get my data.

```
Source      Dummy   Data

Secondary   DUMMY   22134007
Secondary   DUMMY   27543350
Secondary   DUMMY   22128972
Primary     DUMMY   29579399
Secondary   DUMMY   23781175
Primary     DUMMY   1000185771
Primary     DUMMY   22135458
Secondary   DUMMY   022130241
Primary     DUMMY   22137751
Primary     DUMMY   27543359
```

and here's where will I put the data of column `Data` in `source,xlsx` , to `output.xlsx`

```
svc_no      MDF      Primary Data   Secondary Data
1000185771  DUMMY   
22134007    DUMMY       
27543350    DUMMY       
22135458    DUMMY       
22137751    DUMMY       
22128972    DUMMY       
27543359    DUMMY       
29579399    DUMMY       
23781175    DUMMY
```

Now what I want is to put the values of `Data` column in `output.xlsx` by looking up the value of `Source` column in `source.xlsx`

Like this:

This should be the output of the `FinalOutput.xlsx`

```
svc_no      MDF      Primary Data   Secondary Data
1000185771  DUMMY    1000185771         
22134007    DUMMY                   22134007
27543350    DUMMY                   27543350
22135458    DUMMY    22135458
22137751    DUMMY                   22137751
22128972    DUMMY                   22128972
27543359    DUMMY                   27543359
29579399    DUMMY   29579399    
23781175    DUMMY                   23781175
```

The value of `Data` in `source.xlsx` will match the `svc_no` in `output.xlsx` but it should know if it's in `Primary` or `Secondary` column.

This is what I did.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.read_excel("output.xlsx")
df_2 = pd.read_excel("sourcefile2.xlsx", "v0.02")

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2)

Primary = df_2['Source'].str.contains('Primary')
Secondary = df_2['Source'].str.contains('Secondary')

df_1 = df_1[df_1['svc_no'].isin(df_2[Primary]['Data'])]
df_1['Primary Data'] = df_1['svc_no']

df_1 = df_1[df_1['svc_no'].isin(df_2[Secondary]['Data'])]
df_1['Secondary Data'] = df_1['svc_no']

df_1.to_excel('FinalOutput.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pivot`

```
df.reset_index().pivot(index='index',columns='Source',values='Data').fillna('')
Out[179]: 
Source      Primary    Secondary
index                           
0                     2.2134e+07
1                    2.75434e+07
2                     2.2129e+07
3       2.95794e+07             
4                    2.37812e+07
5       1.00019e+09             
6       2.21355e+07             
7                    2.21302e+07
8       2.21378e+07             
9       2.75434e+07
```

After `concat`

```
df.Data=df.Data.astype(str)
pd.concat([df,df.reset_index().pivot(index='index',columns='Source',values='Data').fillna('')],axis=1)
Out[182]: 
      Source  Dummy        Data     Primary Secondary
0  Secondary  DUMMY    22134007              22134007
1  Secondary  DUMMY    27543350              27543350
2  Secondary  DUMMY    22128972              22128972
3    Primary  DUMMY    29579399    29579399          
4  Secondary  DUMMY    23781175              23781175
5    Primary  DUMMY  1000185771  1000185771          
6    Primary  DUMMY    22135458    22135458          
7  Secondary  DUMMY    22130241              22130241
8    Primary  DUMMY    22137751    22137751          
9    Primary  DUMMY    27543359    27543359
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused. The data should match the data in `svc_no` column, and should put it if that data is a `Primary` or `Secondary` by looking up in `source.xlsx`

Comment: @GanzoPalumi that is matched , the scientific may confused u :-)

Comment: Is there a way not to use `concat`? I forgot to mention that my excel output have more columns after the `Primary` and `Secondary` columns and the output starts with the data of `svc_no`

Comment: I have an example above where I will insert the data